# spark how read mongo data to json string? have no use for schema

Tags: apache-spark

Since I need data compatible with all schemas, the default is samplesize 10000. If I turn it up, it will consume a lot of performance and time. I want to convert the data into a complete json without any schema.Is there a simple way to do this?thank you

```
import com.cd.flow.core.utils.ResourcesUtils
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object TestMogonToString {
  Logger.getRootLogger.setLevel(Level.WARN)
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val m6PropValues = ResourcesUtils.getMogodbPropValues("ds6uri", "ds6database")
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").appName(this.getClass.getSimpleName) .getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._
    val m_sql = "[{$match:{'updateTime':{'$gte':'2020-01-08 00:00:00','$lte':'2020-01-08 23:59:59'}}}]"
    println("m_sql", m_sql)
    val lxjStoreMongoDF = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource")
      .option("spark.mongodb.input.uri", m6PropValues._1).option("spark.mongodb.input.database", m6PropValues._2)
      .option("collection", "order").option("pipeline", m_sql)/*.schema(structureSchema)*/.load()
    lxjStoreMongoDF.show()
    lxjStoreMongoDF.printSchema()
    /**
      * +--------------------+-------------+--------+---------+---------------+----------+----------------+......
      * |                 _id|activityPrice| brandId|brandName|cancelBigReason|cancelNote|cancelOperribute|......
      * +--------------------+-------------+--------+---------+---------------+----------+----------------+......
      * |[5e1471dd666bb700...|            0|26000252| 奈雪の茶|              0|          |          null   fals......
      *---------------------------------------------------------------split
      * root
      * |-- _id: struct (nullable = true)
      * |    |-- oid: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- orderDrivers: array (nullable = true)
      * |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
      * |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
      * |    |    |-- phone: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- orderId: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- orderNo: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- orderPreferentials: array (nullable = true)
      * |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
      * |    |    |-- childType: integer (nullable = true)
      * |    |    |-- pid: string (nullable = true)
      * ..........
      */
    //I want that
    /**
      * +--------------------+---------
      * |   jsonstring       |....
      * +--------------------+---------
      * |{_id:100,activityPrice:xx.....}|....
      *---------------------------------------------------------------split
      * root
      * |-- jsonstring: string (nullable = true)
      * ..........
      */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, but it also has samplesize pushed to the schema in the middle. I want to skip the samplesize configuration and go straight to the original full string. I wonder if there is such a way?

```
    val jsonDF = lxjStoreMongoDF.toJSON.withColumnRenamed("value", "msg").withColumn("cd_ods_src", lit("m6"))
    jsonDF.printSchema()
    jsonDF.show()

root
 |-- msg: string (nullable = true)
 |-- cd_ods_src: string (nullable = false)

+--------------------+----------+
|                 msg|cd_ods_src|
+--------------------+----------+
|{"_id":{"oid":"5e...|        m6|
|{"_id":{"oid":"5e...|        m6|
|{"_id":{"oid":"5e...|        m6|
```